# showing no posts on wp_query

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am setting up a custom post type for wordpress and now i'm trying to display the posts on the homepage. I would like to hide the posts until they are called via has_tag i'm using the following code but it displays all of the posts.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'homepage', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
    $loop->the_post();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/33838424/1687983 ?

Comment: *"I would like to hide the posts until they are called via has_tag"* -- What does this mean?

Comment: This is not a duplicate post. This is totally different from the other question I asked. This is with a custom post type and i'm having trouble with all the posts displaying. I tried to set the posts per page to -1 but it doesn't seem to take effect.

Comment: I would like to hide the posts until its called by a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get this accomplished by using the following code.

```
<?php

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'homepage',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<ul>';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
$the_query->the_post();
if (has_tag('footer')) {
echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
}
}
echo '</ul>';
} rewind_posts();




// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
$the_query->the_post();
if (has_tag('cta')) {
echo '<div class="cta-style">' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
}
}

}  ?>
```